# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion, sponsorship

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the Apple community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant Apple conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: @Moderators a banner on the main site linking here asking for communities ideas (maybe not right now, but once the first ideas get flowing) would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas from the developer community:

- [Daniel Jalkut](http://www.red-sweater.com/)
- [Aaron Hillegass](http://bignerdranch.com/)
- [Mark Dalrymple](http://borkware.com/)
- [Marcus Zarra](http://www.cimgf.com/)
- [Matt Gemmell](http://mattgemmell.com/)
- [Matt Gallagher](http://cocoawithlove.com/)
- [Peter Hosey](http://boredzo.org/) ([apple.se](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5736/peter-hosey))
- [Graham Lee](http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/) ([apple.se](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1393/graham-lee))

Or maybe someone from Apple:

- [Bill Dudney](http://bill.dudney.net/)
- [Michael Jurewitz](http://twitter.com/jury)
- [Bill Bumgarner](http://www.friday.com/bbum/) ([apple.se](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bbum))
- [Scott Stevenson](http://theocacao.com/)
- [Greg Parker](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/)
- [Chris Hanson](http://eschatologist.net/)

Comment: @Dori yeah, i realized that well after the fact.  All (or pretty much all) of them are contributors on SO, but not really so much on .se.  I've added links for the couple that do have accounts here.